# ResourceManager class mismatch when using Velocity as OSGi bundle

Tags: java, osgi, classloader, velocity, eclipse-plugin

I am using Apache Velocity in my Eclipse plugin. The corresponding entry has been added to `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Require-Bundle: org.apache.velocity;bundle-version="1.5.0"
```

A Velocity-instance is initialized as follows:

```
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
ve.setProperty(Velocity.RUNTIME_LOG_LOGSYSTEM_CLASS, NullLogChute.class.getName());
ve.init();
```

I build the JAR with my plugin and test it on several machines. On 2 PCs this works fine but on the third one I get an exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.initializeResourceManager(RuntimeInstance.java:589)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:241)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeSingleton.init(RuntimeSingleton.java:113)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.init(Velocity.java:83)
```

It seems I get this exception because Velocity isn't OGSi-friendly. Can anybody give me a workaround?

Comment: Check if you have more than one bundle exporting the org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource package. It may be a wiring conflict.

Comment: I have a bundle `org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen_2.3.100.v201310142259.jar` which has `org.apache.velocity;bundle-version="[1
 .5.0,2.0.0)"` in the manifest. But I've got this bundle on all machines including those where my plugin works fine.

Comment: just guessing (sorry for flood): maybe you have different JVMs and the bundles declare constraints on it?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve similar issue using this : https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_use_the_context_class_loader_in_Eclipse%3F

Basically you set the current Thread class loader to the one of your Eclipse/OSGi plug-in (or a class of your plug-in).

Resulting sample code below works fine with both plain java execution (Run as Java Application) and called through plugin API after exporting the Eclipse product.

```
public class Printer {

  @Override
  public void myPluginApiOverride() {
    Printer.main(new String[0]);
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    // without the following class loader initialization, I get the
    // following exception when running as Eclipse plugin:
    // org.apache.velocity.exception.VelocityException: The specified
    // class for ResourceManager
    // (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not
    // implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager;
    // Velocity is not initialized correctly.
    final ClassLoader oldContextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(Printer.class.getClassLoader());

    // sample velocity call
    final Writer writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
    final VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
    context.put("name", "World");
    try {
      Velocity.evaluate(context, writer, "org.apache.velocity", "Hello $name !");
      writer.close();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // set back default class loader
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(oldContextClassLoader);
  }
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm for my annotation processor to work on eclipse (it was already working on maven)